# Prevent pushing duplicate object in array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a child component that receives data via `@Input()` from parent component (array of objects). I map that data and push object in new array for each object from Input data array in ngOnChanges hook. My goal is to prevent duplicates objects being pushed in new array. Every time ngOnChanges fires new objects are being pushed to `admins` array. I've tried to use `some` method in if statement but it didn't help. Here is my OnChanges hook:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  this.adminsGroup.map(a => {
    this.authService.getSpecUser(a.user).subscribe(
      data => {
        data.position = a.permissions;
        this.admins.push(data);
      }
    )
  });
}
```

So I want to ensure that there is no `data` already in `this.admins` array before pushing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking against a specific property say 'id' in data for uniqueness.

```
if (!this.admins.some(el => el.id === data.id)) {
  this.admins.push(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If data has a unique ID you can just do:

```
let foundAdmin = this.admins.find(admin => admin.id == data.id);
if (foundAdmin == null)
    this.admins.push(data);
```

If it doesn't:

```
let foundAdmin = this.admins.find(admin => JSON.stringify(admin) === JSON.stringify(data));
if (foundAdmin == null)
    this.admins.push(data);
```